# linear interpolation to find corresponding vales from two tables using python

Tags: python, linear-interpolation

i want to write a function that accepts two lists, one of x values and one of y(x) values and returns the corresponding y(x) value when given an x value. i also want to use linear interpolation to find y(x) for values of x between the numbers in the list.
for example

```
f = function([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])
```

`print f(3)`
should return 0.0

so far i don't have a full code but i am attempting to use

`interp1d(numpy.array(xs), numpy.array(ys), 'linear')` for the interpolation

`for i in range(len(xs)):
        return ys[i]` and this for the values in the list, but i dont really know how to put it together

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` your lists and convert to a dictionary then pass the dictionary to `lambda` :

```
>>> f=lambda x: dict(zip([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2]))[x]
>>> f(3)
0
>>> f(4)
1
```

But as the above solution may be raise an `KeyError` you can use the following factory-function :

```
>>> def liner(l1,l2):
...     d=dict(zip(l1,l2))
...     def li(x):
...       try :
...          return d[x]
...       except KeyError:
...          print 'please enter a valid number'
...     return li
... 
>>> f=liner([3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2])
>>> f(9)
please enter a valid number
>>> f(3)
0
>>> f(6)
2
```